# Angular - ngFor is displaying all items in one column

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I'm using `ngFor` to display data in a table and for some reason it's all displaying in the first column. **EDIT** - got this to work but now I'm having trouble with my `ngSwitch`. I'm getting an error on `pto-row-edit` saying that it can't bind to 'pto' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. What I'm trying to do is to have it so that the data is displayed in the grid using `row-display.component` and then whenever a row is selected, to display `row-edit.component` instead.

Here's where I call my `row-edit.component`:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Full/Half</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Scheduled?</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>In P/R?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pto of (ptoData | currentEmployee:empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey)">
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="isRowSelected()">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">
          <tr pto-row-display [pto]="pto" *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType"></tr>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true">
          <tr pto-row-edit [pto]="pto" [rowSelected]="rowSelected" *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType"></tr>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here's my `row-edit.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { PTOData } from './pto-data';

@Component({
    selector: '[pto-row-edit]',
    templateUrl: `./row-edit.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./row-edit.component.css']
})

export class RowEditComponent {
    @Input() pto: PTOData[];
}
```

and here's my `row-edit.component.html`:

```
<td><input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoDate" [ngModel]="pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'" (ngModelChange)="pto.date=$event" name="ptoDate" /></td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoFullHalf" [(ngModel)]="pto.fullhalf" name="ptoFullHalf">
    <option value="full">Full</option>
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>
    <option value="(full)">(Full)</option>
    <option value="(half)">(Half)</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoHours" [(ngModel)]="pto.hours" name="ptoHours">
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="-4">-4</option>
    <option value="-8">-8</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoScheduled" [(ngModel)]="pto.scheduled" name="ptoScheduled">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
    <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
    <option value="unscheduled">Unscheduled</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td><input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoNotes" [(ngModel)]="pto.notes" name="ptoNotes" /></td>
<td>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ptoinPR" [(ngModel)]="pto.inPR" name="ptoinPR" />
</td>
```

I really feel that this should work and I'm not quite sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `table` elements you can't place custom element directly in it. If you add custom element in `table` element they will consider as invalid html and those element will thrown out of `table` tag.

For this case I'd recommend you to make your component selector attribute based and then move `pto.type === selectedType` condition to CustomPipe of `ngFor` so that we can get rid of `ng-container`. Perhaps you can extend `currentEmployee` Pipe itself with `pto.type === selectedType`(this check). Afterwards directly place `pto-row-display` on `tr` as in attribute.

```
selector: '[pto-row-display]'
```

And then use it as attribute

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Full/Half</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
    <th>Scheduled?</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <th>In P/R?</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr 
    *ngFor="let pto of (ptoData | currentEmployee:empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey):selectedType" 
    pto-row-display [pto]="pto">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**currentEmployee Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { PTOData } from './pto-data';

@Pipe({ name: 'currentEmployee' })
export class CurrentEmployee implements PipeTransform {
    transform(allData: PTOData[], key: number, selectedType: any) {
        return (allData ? allData.filter(emp => emp.EmpKey == key && emp.type === selectedType) : []);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PankajParkar where would I put the ngIf check inside my pipe? I've updated my question with the code for the pipe

Comment: `but that isn't going to work with table` - `<ng-container *ngIf` won't work?

Comment: @PankajParkar whenever I change my selector to `Selector: [pto-row-display]`,` I'm getting an error that says `Argument of type '{ selector: number[]; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.`

Comment: What is wrong with it? https://plnkr.co/edit/JtZjxYdtOoXs8u9RPeWV?p=preview

Comment: @PankajParkar okay, thank you. It's compiling now, but I'm getting an error in the browser. I've updated my original post

Comment: @yurzui small query, I did try `<table>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container></ng-container>
      <custom-element></custom-element>
    </tbody>
  </table>` on any html.. and check the DOM by inspecting element.. I'm still wondering why `ng-container`, does it do anything special...?

Comment: `ng-container` is not stamped in the DOM. it's just angular helper. It should not break DOM

Comment: @yurzui whenever I ran it the way you have in the plnkr, I got an error saying "can't bind to 'pto' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'."

Comment: @rcarc Component `[pto-row-display]` should have `@Input() pto` as in my plunkr

Comment: @yurzui okay, I had just forgotten the brackets around pto-row-display. thank you very much. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it for you!

Comment: @yurzui also, I'm having the same problem now with the other half of my switch statement even though it is basically the same as the other half. Why is this?

Comment: @rcarc I already had wrote that thing in my answer.. `selector: '[pto-row-display]'`

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah, I had just put it in and then deleted it for some reason